# Unable to login to MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I get the following errors when I try to access phpmyadmin.

1
mysqli::real_connect(): php_network_getaddresses:
getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

2
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses:
getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Root193782
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mysql-net

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Root193782
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /data/php/admin/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    networks:
      - mysql-net

networks:
  mysql-net:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: seems that your DNS is not working correctly ... and never post real password on sites like this!

Comment: These passwords are examples only.
Thank you very much for your concern.

Answer (score 0):

==================================================

I managed to solve it, passing the environment variables below. below

```
version: '3.7'

networks:
  mysql-net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  mysqldb:
    container_name: mysqldb
    image: mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: Root193782
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mysql-net

  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    environment:
      - PMA_HOSTS=mysqldb
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
      - PMA_USER=root
      - PMA_PASSWORD=Root193782
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /data/php/admin/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
    networks:
      - mysql-net
```